# Zip a directory while retaining relative path

Tags: bash, zip

I have a directory of files:

```
/home/user/files/1.txt
/home/user/files/2.txt
/home/user/files/3.txt
```

I'd like to zip up the `files` directory into `files.zip` so when extracted I get:

```
files/1.txt
files/2.txt
files/3.txt
```

I know I can do:

```
# bash
cd /home/user; zip -r files.zip files/
```

Is there a way to do this without `cd`ing to the `user` directory?

I know that the `--junk-paths` flag will store just the filenames and junk the path but I'd like to keep the `files` directory as a container.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find direct way using zip command but you can try "tar" command with -C option.

**$ pwd**

```
/home/shenzi
```

**$ ls -l giga/files**

```
total 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shenzi Domain Users 3 Aug  5 11:24 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 shenzi Domain Users 4 Aug  5 11:25 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 shenzi Domain Users 9 Aug  5 11:25 3.txt
```

**$ tar -C giga -cvf files.zip files/***

```
files/1.txt
files/2.txt
files/3.txt
```

**$ tar -tvf files.zip**

```
-rw-r--r-- shenzi/Domain Users 3 2014-08-05 11:24 files/1.txt
-rw-r--r-- shenzi/Domain Users 4 2014-08-05 11:25 files/2.txt
-rw-r--r-- shenzi/Domain Users 9 2014-08-05 11:25 files/3.txt
```

USE: **-xvf** to extract

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks for taking the time.  I'll probably end up using this instead.